# how to paste a range multiple time

Tags: vba

```
Sub sbCopyRange()
Range("g2:h14").Copy

Range("g15").Select

ActiveSheet.Paste

Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

now i want to paste same range 165 time continoulsy plz help

Comment: Do You know anything about loops?

Comment: you want to paste it on 165 different sheets?

Comment: This would copy/paste 165 times: `For x = 1 To 165: Range("G2:H14").Copy Destination:=Range("G15"): Next x` , but I'm guessing you don't want it pasting over the same range each time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below Code to copy and paste under each other for 165 times.

First the Code selects the range g2:h14, Count the number of rows and paste the same range after each other:

```
Sub sbCopyRange()

For x = 1 To 165

Range(Cells(2, 7), Cells(14, 8)).Copy 
lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row
Cells(lRow + 1, 7).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

Next x

End Sub
```